Check whether exponential of Brownian motion is martingale and Markov
I have two processes:$$e^{nB_t-\frac{tn^2}{2}}, e^{n(B_t-t)-\frac{n^2}{2}}, n\in R$$
I need to check whether they are martingales and Markov.
Attempt of solution (martingale):$$E\left[e^{nB_t-\frac{tn^2}{2}}|\mathcal{F_s}\right]=E\left[e^{n(B_t-B_s)+nB_s-\frac{tn^2}{2}}|\mathcal{F_s}\right]=e^{nB_s-\frac{tn^2}{2}}E\left[e^{n(B_t-B_s)}\right]=e^{nB_s-\frac{tn^2}{2}}e^{\frac{n^2(t-s)}{2}}=e^{nB_s-\frac{ts^2}{2}}$$
Thus, it is a martingale.
Another exponential:$$E\left[e^{n(B_t-t)-\frac{n^2}{2}}|\mathcal{F_s}\right]=E\left[e^{n(B_t-B_s-t)+nB_s-\frac{n^2}{2}}|\mathcal{F_s}\right]=e^{nB_s-nt-\frac{n^2}{2}}E\left[e^{n(B_t-B_s)}\right]=e^{nB_s-nt-\frac{n^2}{2}}e^{\frac{n^2(t-s)}{2}}$$
Looks like this is not a martingale.
How to check the Markov property?

Your $n$ became an $N,.$

The case $n=0$ is trivial so let's ignore it. Since your processes are strictly monotonic functions of the Markov process $B_t$ it follows that their natural filtration  is the same as that of $B_t\,.$
Let's write
$$
X_t=g(t,B_t)=e^{nB_t-\frac{n^2t}2}\,.
$$
Then ${\cal F}_t^B={\cal F}_t^X$ and $\sigma(X_t)=\sigma(B_t)\,$
and, for any Borel function $f$,
\begin{align}
&\mathbb E\left[f(X_T)\big|{\cal F}_t^X\right]=\mathbb E\left[f\big(g(T,B_T)\big)\big|{\cal F}_t^X\right]\\[2mm]
&=\mathbb E\left[f\big(g(T,B_T)\big)\big|{\cal F}_t^B\right]
\stackrel{B_t\text{ Markov }}=\mathbb E\left[f\big(g(T,B_T)\big)\big|\sigma(B_t)\right]\\[2mm]
&=\mathbb E\left[f(X_T)\big|\sigma(X_t)\right]\,.
\end{align}
This shows that your first process is Markov. The same works for the second.
